# Why di commons classes are not found during runtime?

Tags: java, apache, runtime-error, apache-commons

After a hard fought battle on Google I was able to figure out a way to download and setup the Apache Commons API for Java (all of this just so I can wrap a chunk of text: P). After correctly creating my CLASSPATH, my compiler (mingw for command-line) was able to access the library and compile my file. However when I run it I get a runtime error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apach
e/commons/lang3/text/WordUtils
```

Did I forget to declare the Apache classes somewhere?

The snippet of code with the problem:

```
String strWrap = WordUtils.wrap("A really really really really really long sentence.", 50);
b.drawString(strWrap,20,20);
```

My import statement (s):

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.net.*;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.text.*;
```

By the way I should mention that the CLASSPATH is set as an environment variable, and the `.jar` file from Apache is NOT with the rest of the project, I put it in a separate directory as I plan on using it for several projects.

Comment: You also need specify CLASSPATH when you run not only in compile time. Can you what command do you use to run application?

Comment: (this is an applet) "appletviewer wrap.html"
By the way, I don't specify the CLASSPATH during compilation, I created an environment variable....

Comment: Ok. Than your task is harder. I see 2 ways: you either include all classes from apache commons to you jar and create one big jar or study how to specify classpath in applets.

Comment: could I just include the WordUtils.class file in my jar as I only need that one for this project? If so, how would I then 'import' it?

Comment: I'm not sure if it will work if you include only 1 class. Try to add them all. And you import as usually. No changes in your code.

Comment: And you need include in appropriate package. You can't just put `WordUtils.class` to the root of your jar.

Answer (score 2):

check [CLASS PATH](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html) given properly.
If you are running java class from the `command line`, you need to add the (*current directory*) dot (.).

```
java YourClass -cp .
```

**Update:** If you are using Applet see this [applet Ref](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/applet.html)

> Applet classes are meant to be loaded from the applet's CODEBASE (the
>   directory of the HTML file if no CODEBASE tag is present), not from
>   the CLASSPATH. If you have applet classes in a directory which is in
>   your CLASSPATH, those classes will be allowed to bypass the normal
>   applet security restrictions.

see this [Environment Reference](http://stuff.mit.edu/afs/athena/software/java_v1.1.6/www/environment.html),
[appletviewer](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/appletviewer.html)

**Detailed Explanation:** ([Reference](http://www.ericgiguere.com/articles/deploying-java-applets.html)) 
Some browsers can run Java applets. They do this by having a full-fledged Java interpreter built right into the browser or loaded as a browser extension (or plug-in). **Note that the Java interpreter used by the browser may or may not respect the settings of the CLASSPATH environment variable**, depending on which browser you're using. This can affect what happens when you download applets.

A Java applet is embedded in an HTML page using the  tag, as in:

```
<applet code="main.class" height="100" width="100"></applet>
```

When the browser sees this tag, it does the following:

1. Starts the Java interpreter if it's not already running.
2. Reserves the given amount of space (100x100) on the page and creates a Java container in that space.
3. Downloads the file `main.class` and makes sure it extends `java.applet.Applet` (which itself extends java.awt.Panel). The downloading is done using a simple GET request, much like an image is downloaded.
4. Adds the applet as a child of the container.
5. Calls the `init()` method on the applet, then the `show()` method.

Comment: This is an applet so I am using the appletviewer which does not support the "-cp" argument

Comment: Allright so I found a way to add a CLASSPATH during runtime ("-J-classpath -J<CLASSPATH>"). However I am just wondering, why can't appletviewer see my environment variables? The class path is set there.?